# Which game portals support Silverlight games?

Tags: silverlight, support

I have been looking for strong game portals that support Silverlight.  Which ones are currently available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.mashooo.com has quite a few Silverlight games.

Answer (score 1):

[GameJolt](http://gamejolt.com/) is pretty awesome!

Comment: GameJolt supports silverlight???

Comment: Sure. GameJolt supports Flash, Silverlight, Unity3D and Java Applet.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.silverarcade.com/ is dedicated to Silverlight only, that's the only one I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.vectorlight.net/games.aspx has Silverlight and HTML5 games you can submit to.